# Spring AMQP and CachingConnectionFactory

Tags: spring-amqp

If I have a CachingConnectionFactory with two addresses, how can I know at any time which server I am connected to? And what would be the best way to manually change from one to the other?

```
CachingConnectionFactory cf = new CachingConnectionFactory(factory);
String _addresses = host + ":" + port + "," + host2 + ":" + port2;
cf.setAddresses(_addresses);
```

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To know the `host/port` you are connected you should consult already the target `NetworkConnection`:

```
/** Retrieve address of peer. */
InetAddress getAddress();

/** Retrieve port number of peer. */
int getPort();
```

That's not `CachingConnectionFactory`  to control that info.

On another hand that `addresses` option is exactly about this:

```
 * @param addrs an array of known broker addresses (hostname/port pairs) to try in order
```

See `com.rabbitmq.client.ConnectionFactory#createConnection()`.

So, all the addresses entries must be in the same cluster. Otherwise you may end up with unexpected behavior when the same name might be used for different entities on different servers.

To control manually I would suggest to change that `setAddresses()` property at runtime or have different `CachingConnectionFactory` instances with different orders.

Comment: Thanks Artem, I have implemented the interface ConnectionListener and I get the URL in the onCreate method.